# Changing pages with a single link but keeping the hash part

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, hyperlink

there is 2 pages, 1 is `ENG.html` another 1 is `GER.html`., and there is some tabs in those 2 pages, their link is: `eng.html#work` `eng.html#about` `eng.html#home`

when click on change language link i need to stay on #work or #home wherever i was, how to do it? please don't post php, html and javascript and others are acceptable, and i don't want to create 2 separate (ENG, GER) folder, any suggestions?

Comment: _Any suggestions_? How about showing some effort.

Comment: @putvande Is it that painful to answer a really, really simple question?

Comment: @Bluefire The idea of SO is to help with problems occurred in an existing program rather than being a free coding service. There should be no difference, whether the question is simple or not.

Comment: Indeed. However, I would argue that **any suggestions** does not warrant a response such as that of putvande. You don't **have** to show any work done, it's just appreciated if you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// set the url we're going to
var url = "GER.html", // for example
// get the hashtag text
hash = window.location.hash,    
// make the new url
loc = url + hash;
// finally, go there
window.location.href = loc;
```